# Powershell pass variable to start-job

Tags: variables, powershell, start-job

within powershell I'd like to learn the best way to call a variable to a start job so I don't have to edit the script for each server as it will be specific based on the client I've placed my script on.

```
$Servername = 'Server1'
    $pingblock = {
      pathping $servername | Out-File C:\client\PS\ServerPing.TXT
    }
    start-job $pingblock
```

when I run my code above I just get a file with the help as if I forgot the specify the $servername.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use the `-ArgumentList` parameter on `Start-Job` e.g.:

```
Start-Job -Scriptblock {param($p) "`$p is $p"} -Arg 'Server1'
```

In your case:

```
$pingblock = {param($servername) pathping $servername | Out-File C:\...\ServerPing.txt}
Start-Job $pingblock -Arg Server1
```

Answer (score 52):

To complement [Keith Hill's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10075995/45375) with a **PSv3+ alternative**:

The **[`$using:` scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#the-using-scope-modifier)** can be used to reference the values of variables in the caller's scope inside the script block passed to `Start-Job`, as an alternative to passing arguments (by default, a script block executed as a background job does *not* see any of the caller's variables or other definitions):

```bash
$Servername = 'Server1'
Start-Job { "Target: " + $using:ServerName } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

The above yields:

```
Target: Server1
```

Note:

- The same technique can be used with:

  - [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) for *remote* execution - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35492437/45375).
  - [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob), available by default in  PowerShell (Core) v6+, installable on demand in Windows PowerShell.
  - [`ForEach-Object -Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1), available in PowerShell (Core) v7+ only.
- Note that, **as with `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`), it is only variable *values* that are being passed, not the *variables themselves*; that is, you cannot *modify* the caller's variables.**<sup>[1]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] However, the *thread*-based concurrency features - `Start-ThreadJob` and `ForEach-Object Parallel` - permit *indirect* modification, namely if the variable value at hand happens to be an instance of a (mutable) .NET *reference type*, such as a hashtable, in which case *the object that that the variable "points to"* can be modified (if it is mutable). Note that taking advantage of that requires additional, nontrivial effort to make the concurrent modifications *thread-safe*, such as by use of concurrent (synchronized) collections - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71146407/45375) - and/or explicit locking of individual objects - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74904460/45375).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Some other ways, $args and $input.  This goes for invoke-command too, which I think uses the same mechanism.  The $input method works in an unexpected way with arrays.

```
start-job { $args[0] } -args hi | receive-job -wait -auto
hi


echo hi | start-job { $input } | receive-job -wait -auto
hi


echo hi there | start-job { $input.gettype() } | receive-job -wait -auto

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
False    False    <GetReadEnumerator>d__20                 System.Object
```

For arrays, it's probably better to use a foreach-object (%) loop instead, so it runs on each array item in parallel.  See also start-threadjob or foreach-object -parallel in powershell 7.  There's actually no -throttlelimit option to start-job, so use with care.

```
echo yahoo.com facebook.com |
   % { $_ | start-job { test-netconnection $input } } |
   receive-job -wait -auto | select * -exclude runspaceid,pssourcejob* | ft

ComputerName RemoteAddress ResolvedAddresses PingSucce
                                             eded
------------ ------------- ----------------- ---------
yahoo.com    74.6.143.25   {74.6.143.25,...} True
facebook.com 31.13.71.36   {31.13.71.36}     True
```