# Pass Input Object to Start-Job File

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I can't seem to figure out why the input passed to start-job disappears.  I have this code in one script:

```
$data = "some test string data"
Start-Job -FilePath ".\Tasks.ps1" -InputObject $data
```

And in the `tasks.ps1` script I get a null value for the `$input` object unless I call it immediately but disappears after doing so:

```
$input #displays the data
$input #null
```

I've tried immediately assigning it to another variable (`$newvalue = $input`) but the value of that variable shows null too.

What am I missing here?  How do I retain the input data?

Comment: @jamesantiago I have find this start-job question and answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075943/powershell-pass-variable-to-start-job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've found the issue.  The $input object is passed as a [PilelineReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms551699%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which I'm assuming is ReadToEnd when called in the job.  When I assign the $input to a variable I'm sending the PipeLineReader instead of its value.  To get around this I used this:

```
[string]$newData = $input
```

This did the trick in preventing a read action happening when accessing the object.