# Powershell runspaces clipboard interaction

Tags: powershell, function, clipboard, interaction, runspace

I've recently gotten around to using `runspaces`, but I've a wall of sorts.
I had this little script where one of the functions sets clipboard to a predefined text.
When run in default runspace it works perfectly. As soon as I placed the script in a runspace, it fails to execute the way I want. I assume that each runspace has its own clipboard. Is there a way to interact with default runspace clipboard from within another one or call a function outside runspace from within it?

Comment: As I see it, your sub-threads should interact with the main thread using a [Synchronized Hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.synchronized) and your main thread should than update the clipboard.

Comment: I am aware of Synchronized Hashtbles, used then with GUI forms. What I don't understand how to do is how to initiate function based on hashtable value changed.
Any ideas?

Comment: You might find some examples in [Powershell pass variable to start-job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57281995/1701026) and [Access current PowerShell instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71141243/1701026). If that doesn't work for you, I suggest that you add the attempt to your question with more details about the specific issues and expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **PowerShell 7+** something like this would work out of the box:

```
$ps = [powershell]::Create().AddScript{
    Set-Clipboard 'foo bar baz'
    Start-Sleep 5
}
$async = $ps.BeginInvoke()
$ps.EndInvoke($async)
$ps.Dispose()

(Get-Clipboard) -eq 'foo bar baz' # True
```

In **Windows PowerShell** its a bit more trickier, you must use a [`Runspace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) setting the [`Runspace.ApartmentState` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace.apartmentstate?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#system-management-automation-runspaces-runspace-apartmentstate) to [`STA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.apartmentstate?view=net-7.0):

```
$rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$rs.ApartmentState = [System.Threading.ApartmentState]::STA
$rs.Open()
$ps = [powershell]::Create().AddScript{
    Set-Clipboard 'foo bar baz'
    Start-Sleep 5
}
$ps.Runspace = $rs
$async = $ps.BeginInvoke()
$ps.EndInvoke($async)
$ps, $rs | ForEach-Object Dispose

(Get-Clipboard) -eq 'foo bar baz' # True
```

Inspecting the [`Error` stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psdatastreams.error?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#system-management-automation-psdatastreams-error) before disposing can always give you a good hint of what could've gone wrong, i.e. using [`Clipboard.SetText` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.settext?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) if not using STA we would get this error:

> Exception calling "SetText" with "1" argument(s): "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it."

Same goes for `Set-Clipboard` which uses the same API, different method, behind the scenes:

```
Message        : Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure
                 that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.
Data           : {}
InnerException :
TargetSite     : Void SetDataObject(System.Object, Boolean, Int32, Int32)
StackTrace     :    at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(Object data, Boolean copy, Int32 retryTimes, Int32
                 retryDelay)
                    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetClipboardCommand.SetClipboardContent(List`1 contentList,
                 Boolean append, Boolean asHtml)
                    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetClipboardCommand.EndProcessing()
                    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.Complete()
HelpLink       :
Source         : System.Windows.Forms
HResult        : -2146233056
```

Comment: THIS IS GOLD. Solution and explanation in one. Added apartment state property and now it works.