# Error access to variable after try catch in PowerShell 7

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, foreach-object, powershell-7.3

i received this error on PowerShell 7:

```
Total Urls to process: 12496
i: 1 | total:
RuntimeException:
Line |
  45 |      $percent = [int](100 * $i / $lines)
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Attempted to divide by zero.
```

development this script:

```
$srcfile = "C:\Users\wnune\OneDrive\Escritorio\imagenes\cardlist.txt"
$urls = Get-Content $srcfile
$lines = 0
switch -File $srcfile { default { ++$lines } }
Write-Host "Total Urls to process: $lines "
$i = 0
Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading files" -Status "In progress" -PercentComplete $i;
$urls | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $url = $_
    try {
        $filename = Split-Path $url -Leaf
        $destination = "C:\Users\wnune\OneDrive\Escritorio\imagenes\$filename"
        $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($response.StatusCode -ne 200) {
            Write-Warning "============================================="
            Write-Warning "Url $url return Error. "
            continue
        }
        if (Test-Path $destination) {
            Write-Warning "============================================="
            Write-Warning "File Exist in Destination: $filename "
            continue
        }
        $job = Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $destination -Asynchronous
        while (($job | Get-BitsTransfer).JobState -eq "Transferring" -or ($job | Get-BitsTransfer).JobState -eq "Connecting")
        {
            Start-Sleep -m 250
        }
        Switch(($job | Get-BitsTransfer).JobState)
        {
            "Transferred" {
                Complete-BitsTransfer -BitsJob $job
            }
            "Error" {
                $job | Format-List
            }
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        Write-Warning "============================================="
        Write-Warning "There was an error Downloading"
        Write-Warning "url:         $url"
        Write-Warning "file:        $filename"
        Write-Warning "Exception Message:"
        Write-Warning "$($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
    
    $i++
    Write-Host "i: $i | total: $lines"
    $percent = [int](100 * $i / $lines)
    Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading files" -Status "In progress" -PercentComplete $percent
}
Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading files" -Status "Completed" -Completed
```

Assuming this is because I'm implementing -Parallel try using a sync object:

```
$syncObject = [System.Object]::new()
$srcfile = "C:\Users\wnune\OneDrive\Escritorio\imagenes\cardlist.txt"
$urls = Get-Content $srcfile
$lines = 0
switch -File $srcfile { default { ++$lines } }
Write-Host "Total Urls to process: $lines "
$i = 0
Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading files" -Status "In progress" -PercentComplete $i;
$urls | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    [System.Threading.Monitor]::Enter($syncObject)
    try {
        $url = $_
        $filename = Split-Path $url -Leaf
        $destination = "C:\Users\wnune\OneDrive\Escritorio\imagenes\$filename"
        $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($response.StatusCode -ne 200) {
            Write-Warning "============================================="
            Write-Warning "Url $url return Error. "
            continue
        }
        if (Test-Path $destination) {
            Write-Warning "============================================="
            Write-Warning "File Exist in Destination: $filename "
            continue
        }
        $job = Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $destination -Asynchronous
        while (($job | Get-BitsTransfer).JobState -eq "Transferring" -or ($job | Get-BitsTransfer).JobState -eq "Connecting")
        {
            Start-Sleep -m 250
        }
        Switch(($job | Get-BitsTransfer).JobState)
        {
            "Transferred" {
                Complete-BitsTransfer -BitsJob $job
            }
            "Error" {
                $job | Format-List
            }
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        Write-Warning "============================================="
        Write-Warning "There was an error Downloading"
        Write-Warning "url:         $url"
        Write-Warning "file:        $filename"
        Write-Warning "Exception Message:"
        Write-Warning "$($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
    finally 
    {
        $i++
        Write-Host "i: $i | total: $lines"
        $percent = [int](100 * $i / $lines)
        Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading files" -Status "In progress" -PercentComplete $percent
        [System.Threading.Monitor]::Exit($syncObject)
    }
}
Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading files" -Status "Completed" -Completed
```

get another error:

```
Total Urls to process: 12496
MethodInvocationException:
Line |
   2 |      [System.Threading.Monitor]::Enter($syncObject)
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "Enter" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null."
```

I have no idea what is wrong or why this happens, if I am respecting the order of execution and I am creating the synchronization object from the beginning; Can someone help me with this???

the main idea is to process the 12496 Urls... and create a progress bar based on the number of Urls processed in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

The PowerShell v7+ [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) `-Parallel` feature
uses separate, *thread*-based runspaces to execute code in parallel.

As in any PowerShell code ([script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), `{ ... }`) that executes *out of runspace*, you must **use the [`$using:` scope](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables#using-local-variables) in order
to refer to variable values in the *caller*'s scope**.

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012780/45375) provides an overview of *all* contexts in which `$using:` is required.

A simple example:

```bash
$i = 42
1..3 |
  ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      'Thread-local $i' = $i
      '$using:i value' = $using:i
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
Thread-local $i $using:i value
--------------- --------------
                            42
                            42
                            42
```

As you can see, the `$i` variable has no value, because it refers to a thread-local (runspace-local) variable that hasn't been initialized.

---

***Updating* values in the caller's scope:**

`$using:` references are only ever the *values* of variables from the caller's scopes, not the *variables themselves*.

If values happen to be instance of .NET *reference types*, you *can* (potentially) update them, by setting their properties and/or calling their methods, but this does *not* work for values that happen to be instances of *value types*, such as `[int]`.

In order to update instances of the latter, wrap them in a reference type, such as a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables).

In order **to make *updating* a value *thread-safe*, explicit synchronization is required**, such as via [`System.Threading.Monitor`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Threading.Monitor):<sup>Thanks, [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon).</sup>

```bash
$iWrapper = @{ Value = 42 }
1..3 |
  ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    # Lock the hashtable so that no other thread can update it.
    [System.Threading.Monitor]::Enter($using:iWrapper)
      # Update its (one and only) entry.
      (++($using:iWrapper).Value)
    # Release the lock.
    [System.Threading.Monitor]::Exit($using:iWrapper)
  }
```

Output:

```
43
44
45
```

Comment: why the other answer, not have an implement example like this?

Comment: i havce try to implement it and get error when y try to: `$using:i++`

Comment: @ArcanisGK507, `$using:` references are variable _values_, not _variables_, so you cannot update _variables_, but you can act on instances of .NET _reference types_ (and then you may need cross-thread synchronization, as you've attempted).

Comment: @ArcanisGK507, as for the other answer: it attempts to provide a _general overview_ of all contexts where `$using:` is required. By linking to the relevant documentation, the rules for concrete usage of `$using:` can be _inferred_.

Comment: so nothing I've seen works... the idea is to count the urls iterated in each thread in parallel... hahahahaha this seems like a joke... I assume that the synchronization object that is in my second example script is the path correct and not implement $using: scope as you suggested

Comment: i will try with $global:i ... i read about it .. but progress bar is out of scope i think XD

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon i use [System.Threading.Monitor] and get error ... XD

Comment: At the moment i have other error; use [hashtable] is working first time in re-run i get ***Exception setting "CursorPosition": "A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. Try a host program that supports user interaction, such as the PowerShell Console, and remove prompt-related commands from command types that do not support user interaction."***

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon but if i whant to increace the value of a property inside $syncObject like a counter???

Comment: chek my wife have create a question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74905498/20850232 becouse i cant do that ... so SO show say that my question is low quality lol ...