# Progress bar is not showing correctly in PowerShell 7 in ForEach -Parallel

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.3

**this show 0%:**

[image]

**this show 4%:**

[image]

**the realted script:**

```
$iWrapper = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{ i = 0 })
$srcfile = "C:\Users\wnune\OneDrive\Escritorio\imagenes\cardlist.txt"
$urls = Get-Content $srcfile
$lines = 0
switch -File $srcfile { default { ++$lines } }
Write-Host "Total Urls to process: $lines "
Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading files" -Status "In progress" -PercentComplete $i;
$urls | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    try {
        $url = $_
        $filename = Split-Path $url -Leaf
        $destination = "C:\Users\wnune\OneDrive\Escritorio\imagenes\$filename"
        $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($response.StatusCode -ne 200) {
            Write-Warning "============================================="
            Write-Warning "Url $url return Error. "
            continue
        }
        if (Test-Path $destination) {
            Write-Warning "============================================="
            Write-Warning "File Exist in Destination: $filename "
            continue
        }
        $job = Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $destination -Asynchronous
        while (($job | Get-BitsTransfer).JobState -eq "Transferring" -or ($job | Get-BitsTransfer).JobState -eq "Connecting")
        {
            Start-Sleep -m 250
        }
        Switch(($job | Get-BitsTransfer).JobState)
        {
            "Transferred" {
                Complete-BitsTransfer -BitsJob $job
            }
            "Error" {
                $job | Format-List
            }
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        Write-Warning "============================================="
        Write-Warning "There was an error Downloading"
        Write-Warning "url:         $url"
        Write-Warning "file:        $filename"
        Write-Warning "Exception Message:"
        Write-Warning "$($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
    $j = ++($using:iWrapper).i
    $k = $using:lines
    $percent = [int](100 * $j / $k)
    Write-Host "PercentCalculated: $percent"
    Write-Host "Progress bar not Show the %"
    Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading files " -Status " In progress $percent" -PercentComplete $percent
}
Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading files" -Status "Completed" -Completed
```

*If I am passing in `-PercentComplete $percent` which is an `integer` why does the progress bar not receive it correctly?*

I have verified that the script and the environment are correctly configured but I cannot validate because the progress bar is not seen correctly.

Comment: Clearly a duplicate from your previous question and there is too much code going on. What specific problem you want to solve? displaying progress from multiple threads? if so, why is all the other irrelevant code there? it's an instant turn off to answer your question

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon According to what I investigated, it is not the same problem, I am trying to monitor the progress bar but apparently it was removed because I am not sure with -parallel I am looking for an alternative that I can use as a progress bar, I found a call Posh-Progresbar but it is no longer there in the repositories...

Comment: `Start-BitsTransfer` can download and track progress in parallel by itself without parallel loop or anything else. Are you aware of that?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon yes but i am downloading around 15k image from web with diferent url of sources in the txt source given ... i need track by amount of image donwloaded not the size of all image ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 baby, I didn't think this was so stupidly complex... I think I can do much easier with a graphical interface in .net

Comment: @MinosFramework you can try it, tomorrow i will be home early in the morning and we will talk about this... powershell does not have what i expected.

Comment: Have a good look at your code again, break it done, to me it's overly complicated. You're calling `Start-BitsTransfer` with `-Asynchronous` yet not leveraging it's async capabilities because each thread is waiting for their bits transfer to finish (this doesn't make any sense). The cmdlet can take a CSV as input with all URL sources and their corresponding destination paths and do all this work by itself in parallel. `ForEach-Object -Parallel` has nothing to do here.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon i try that you say and get a lot of background threat of cmdlet with around 2mb ram consumption for every of 15000 url broken my memory ...

Comment: Then process this download in chunks: read the CSV -> pass a chunk of objects (say 20 objects / 20 downloads) to `Start-BitsTransfer` -> block the processing until it finishes -> pass next chunk and so on.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I assume that orEach-Object -Parallel will have some limitation regarding the number of open threads so it doesn't cause the problem I just described... I've already tried several things before getting to this point... Thanks for your time and your contributions, they have really helped me to understand more about how to pass data; but the progress bar is a lead...

Comment: even tho Runspaces are very efficient certainly 15k threads is not an option, you will have the same problem. You need just 10 to 15 threads and pass a chunk of 15k URLs divided by threads to each one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250630/discussion-between-arcanisgk507-and-santiago-squarzon).

Answer (score 4):

I propose a much easier solution: piping the results to another foreach-object which isn't parallel to display the progress-bar. have a look at the test code, it will be clearer:

```
# Generate data
$list = 1..100

# Processing data
$list |
    ForEach-Object -parallel {
        # Simulate thread activity of varying duration.
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds (Get-Random -Min 0 -max 300)
        # Produce output
        $_
    } |
    # Piping the results to a queued foreach-object which 
    # will write progress as results are delivered
    ForEach-Object -Begin { $received = 0 } -Process { 
        # incrementing result count
        $received += 1
        # Calculate the percentage completed.
        [int] $percentComplete = ($received / $list.Count) * 100
        # update progress bar
        Write-Progress -Activity Test -Status "$percentComplete% complete" -PercentComplete $percentComplete
        # returning the result
        $_
    }
```

Comment: Indeed, that is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Note:

- A *potential future enhancement*  has been proposed in [GitHub issue #13433](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13433), suggesting adding parameter(s) such as `-ShowProgressBar` to `ForEach-Object -Parallel` so that it would *automatically* show a progress bar based on how many parallel threads have completed so far.
- A *simpler* solution than the ones below can be found in [miljbee's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77010074/45375), which simply delegates updating the progress play to an *additional, non-parallel* `ForEach-Object` call, which receives the outputs from the parallel threads as they are being emitted.

---

Leaving the discussion about whether `Start-BitsTransfer` alone is sufficient aside:

**At least as of PowerShell v7.3.1, it seemingly *is* possible to call `Write-Progress` from inside threads created by [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)  `-Parallel`**, based on a running counter of how many threads have exited so far.

However, there are two **challenges**:

- You cannot directly update a counter variable in the *caller's* runspace (thread), you can only refer to an *object* that is an instance of a [.NET *reference type*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) in the caller's runspace...
- ...and modifying such an object, e.g. a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) must be done in a thread-safe manner, such as via [`System.Threading.Monitor`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Threading.Monitor).

Note that I don't know whether calling [`Write-Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress) from different threads is officially supported, but it seems to work in practice, at least when the call is made in a thread-safe manner, as below.

- **Bug alert**, as of PowerShell 7.3.1: Irrespective of whether you use `ForEach-Object -Parallel` or not, If you call `Write-Progress` *too quickly in succession*, only the *first* in such a sequence of calls takes effect:

  - See [GitHub issue #18848](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18848)
  - As a **workaround**, the code below inserts a `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200` call after each `Write-Progress` call.

    - Not only should this not be necessary, it slows down overall execution, because threads then take longer to exit, which affects not only a given thread, but overall execution time, because it delays when threads "give up their slot" in the context of thread throttling (`5` threads are allowed to run concurrently by default; use `-ThrottleLimit` to change that.

A simple proof of concept:

```bash
# Sample pipeline input
$urls = 1..100 | ForEach-Object { "foo$_" }

# Helper hashtable to keep a running count of completed threads.
$completedCount = @{ Value = 0 }

$urls | 
  ForEach-Object -parallel { # Process the input objects in parallel threads.

    # Simulate thread activity of varying duration.
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds (Get-Random -Min 0 -max 3000)
    # Produce output.
    $_

    # Update the count of completed threads in a thread-safe manner
    # and update the progress display.
    [System.Threading.Monitor]::Enter($using:completedCount) # lock access
      ($using:completedCount).Value++
      # Calculate the percentage completed.
      [int] $percentComplete = (($using:completedCount).Value / ($using:urls).Count) * 100
      # Update the progress display, *before* releasing the lock.
      Write-Progress -Activity Test -Status "$percentComplete% complete" -PercentComplete $percentComplete
      # !! Workaround for the bug above - should *not* be needed.
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
    [System.Threading.Monitor]::Exit($using:completedCount) # release lock

  }
```

---

An **alternative approach** in which the *calling* thread centrally tracks the progress of all parallel threads:

Doing so requires adding the `-AsJob` switch to `ForEach-Object -Parallel`, which, instead of the *synchronous* execution that happens by default, starts a (thread-based) [*background job*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs), and returns a [`[System.Management.Automation.PSTasks.PSTaskJob]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSTasks.PSTaskJob) instance that represents all parallel threads as PowerShell (thread) jobs in the `.ChildJobs` property.

A simple proof of concept:

```bash
# Sample pipeline input
$urls = 1..100 | ForEach-Object { "foo$_" }

Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading files" -Status "Initializing..."

# Launch the parallel threads *as a background (thread) job*.
$job = 
  $urls |
    ForEach-Object -AsJob -Parallel {
      # Simulate thread activity of varying duration.
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds (Get-Random -Min 0 -max 3000)
      $_ # Sample output: pass the URL through
    }

# Monitor and report the progress of the thread job's 
# child jobs, each of which tracks a parallel thread.
do {

  # Sleep a bit to allow the threads to run - adjust as desired.
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 

  # Determine how many jobs have completed so far.
  $completedJobsCount  = 
     $job.ChildJobs.Where({ $_.State -notin 'NotStarted', 'Running' }).Count

  # Relay any pending output from the child jobs.
  $job | Receive-Job

  # Update the progress display.
  [int] $percent = ($completedJobsCount / $job.ChildJobs.Count) * 100
  Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading files" -Status "$percent% complete" -PercentComplete $percent

} while ($completedJobsCount -lt $job.ChildJobs.Count)

# Clean up the job.
$job | Remove-Job
```

While this is more work and less efficient due to the polling loop, it has two advantages:

- The script blocks running in the parallel threads need not be burdened with progress-reporting code.
- The polling loop affords the opportunity to perform other foreground activity while the parallel threads are running in the background.
- The bug discussed above needn't be worked around, assuming your `Start-Sleep` interval in the polling loop is at least 200 msecs.

Comment: I have tried your example and it doesn't work correctly; according to what has happened; First it downloads all the files and then it makes the progress bar...

Comment: this is the script with my modifications: https://gist.github.com/arcanisgk/ace898aef6423650cdea73e4ad6024b5

Comment: but implementing Write-Host i get this: https://i.imgur.com/FHYgvAp.png apparently other error handling messages are interfering with the progress bar; I would have to place that progress bar on the bottom line of the screen... I'm going to investigate the subject...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507, I had a misconception about output timing  re `ForEach-Object -Parallel`, so the `Write-Progress` bug I thought existed doesn't. However, a _different_ bug does exist, and it is per se not related to parallel execution. Please see my update, which shows that calling `Write-Progress` from parallel threads _can_ be made to work - at least in my proof of concept, on PowerShell 7.3.1 The job-based alternative should work too.